# Creature Ability List

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Sudden Spoiling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=113525) reads

> Creatures target player controls become 0/2 and lose all abilities until end of turn.

Can someone help me find a list of abilities that they lose?

Answer (score 8):

From the comp rules glossary:

> 1. Text on an object that explains what that object does or can do.
> 2. An activated or triggered ability on the stack. This kind of ability is an object.

Every item of rules text in the text box (the box in the lower half of the card) is an ability. Doesn't matter whether it's keywords or full statements; static, triggered, or activated. In addition, lands with a basic land type have an implied ability: "T: Add 1 [color] mana to your mana pool."

In handwavy terms, "lose all abilities" means "pretend there's nothing printed in the card's textbox".

More precisely, you apply effects that add or take away abilities in "timestamp" order. So, for example:

1. I have a [Stampeding Rhino](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244825). It has one ability: trample.
2. I enchant my Rhino with [Trollhide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220190). This gives my Rhino a second ability: "1G: Regenerate this creature" (the ability is printed on the Trollhide card, but it as an ability that the card gave **to the Rhino**).
3. My opponent plays [Turn to Frog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220265) on my Rhino, which includes the text "loses all abilities". My Rhino now has no abilities, until end of turn. Both the Rhino's built-in trample and its enchantment-granted regeneration are removed.
4. After my Rhino is turned into a Frog, I activate [Alabaster Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220264) to give it lifelink until end of turn. Now my Frog has one ability: lifelink.

(Power/toughness-modifying effects are actually a bit trickier, since they are applied in layers. So the Frog is 3/3, not 1/1. That's a different question.)

Answer (score 3):

Alex's answer is quite complete, however his quoted point 2 leaves the impression that an ability on the stack would be affected.  This is incorrect.

From the [Gatherer rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=113525) on this card

> Sudden Spoiling doesn't counter abilities that have already triggered or been activated. In particular, you can't cast this fast enough to stop a creature's "At the beginning of your upkeep" or "When this creature enters the battlefield" abilities from triggering.

However he's quite correct in pointing out the way that new effects would interact with cards you had already suddenly spoiled :)  It should be clear as well that any creature cast after your Sudden Spoiling would not be affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for - as keyworded abilities are only a *subset of all abilities*, but this page has an up-to-date list of keyword abilities in Magic the Gathering, which you may find fun to peruse:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_keywords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic%3a_The_Gathering_keywords)

Having said the above, I don't think you'll ever find a more complete list of abilities that are removed by Sudden Spoiling; as such a list would have to include all the non-flavour-text text written on thousands upon thousands of Magic cards!